# InDesign misaligned table borders when printed

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, borders, tables

When I export InDesign file to PDF for print, the table looks fine.

When printed, it shows the border misaligned with table row background fills.

In the example below, the blue border is set at the top of the row, sorry for the cropped table preview. Without zooming in, it looks fine. When printed, it's show even more misalignment on the sides.

Should play with adding the borders on the side as well? I can't really figure it out to get a proper and sharp look.

I need the headers on the white background to be aligned on the left, at the beginning of the row. Also, when I add left border to the next cells, it appears like a joined vertical line.

[image: table - top row blue border]

Comment: I know what you are talking about. I think the stroke *is* the same width as the cell, but there is some kind of setting on the vector objects which causes this. I can come up with a few workarounds (covering the side of the table with a white rectangle, pasting the table into a frame and cropping off a bit), but no real solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about a gap that appears between the top of the top cell's grey fill and the blue stroke. If this is the case, then you can fill the table's text frame with that same grey color, then make sure any transparent cells are filled with white. The appearance should be the same as what you posted, but any gaps errors from the printing process should be filled by the background grey color. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the blue stroke being [1 px wider than the gray fill](https://i.imgur.com/TU8K2rH.png) in the screenshot. This is apparently also visible on print. I think I've encountered this problem before.

Comment: You might be right. I think the solution would still work.